# how to solve the values changed when converting a pytorch Variable to numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, resnet

I am trying to convert a parameter of resnet34 to numpy , but I found that the values would change after converting, as shown in the figure.
Why would this happen? What can I do to get precise values in numpy format?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkVeG.png)

( I am trying to get parameter in torch pretrained models and put them in tensorflow 1.x model , since I can’t find a pretrained resnet34 models in tensorflow1 afteing searching for several days. I am afraid this changed of values would affect the accuracy of the model. )

(BTW, is there someway to download tensorflow1.x resnet34 pretrained modles with basic block instead of bottleneck block? 
I have searched in github for several days but failed to find one. I hate tensorflow.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are not changed, they are identical, but PyTorch limits the default output to 4 decimal places (which gets rounded) to make it easier to inspect.

You can change that behaviour with [`torch.set_printoptions`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_printoptions) to show more decimal places.

```py
value = torch.tensor(0.0052872747)

print(value) # => tensor(0.0053)

# Show 10 decimal places
torch.set_printoptions(precision=10)

print(value) # => tensor(0.0052872747)
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much! what a nice web stackoverflow is!

Answer (score 0):

Values are technically same, just rounded upt04 decimal places.

Use the following code and you should have identical output:

```py
print(round(weight_np[0,0,0,0],4))
```

Comment: thx a lot! So is the numpy value precise?(Sorry I am not familiar with Pytorch soI have to make it sure)

Answer (score 0):

The default number of digits of precision for floating point output is 4. See [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_printoptions).

You can set it to let's say 8 digits as follows:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([0.01298734, 0.00689523])
print(a) # tensor([0.0130, 0.0069])
torch.set_printoptions(precision=8)
print(a) # tensor([0.01298734, 0.00689523])
```